# Laravel validation required_if with in:1

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5

I need to use required_id with a in:1 as this field is required to be checked only if another field equal to 4

```
'affirm_agency' => 'required_if:role,4|in:1',
```

but when I write it that way I can't pass the validation when it doesn't equal to 1

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class userRequest extends FormRequest
{
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
 public function authorize()
 {
    return false;
 }
  public function rules()
   {
       return [    'affirm_agency' => 'required_if:role,4|in:1',];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically handle something like this like so:

```
/**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules() : array
{
    $rules = [
        // add whatever default rules you always want
    ];

    if (request()->role == 4) {
        $rules['affirm_agency'] = 'required|in:1';
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Please see laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-in)

in:foo,bar,...

The field under validation must be included in the given list of values. Since this rule often requires you to implode an array, the Rule::in method may be used to fluently construct the rule:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
    'zones' => [
        'required',
        Rule::in(['first-zone', 'second-zone']),
    ],
]);
```

You need to update you authorize function as it is returning false now.

```
public function authorize()
 {
    return true;
 }
```

Comment: <?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class userRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return false;
    }
   public function rules()
    {
        return [    'affirm_agency' => 'required_if:role,4|in:1',];
    }
}

the code is just like that